# Lucene Spatial Search Support Module Not Working with 8.1

Tags: content-search, lucene

I need your help!

Has anyone gotten the Lucene Spatial Search Support module to work in 8.1 that can provide me a tip or hint. From my research, and what I have done to this point, it should be working but it's not bringing back any results. Here is what I have done:

I brought down the code from GitHub to my local, and upgraded the .dlls for 8.1 rev. 160302. Got it building and then took those .dll's and brought them over to my solution. Now when I publish they are going over just fine to my Website folder. I then modified my "locations" index to include the  and  sections along with this change to the index assembly:

```
<index id="locations" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Spatial.Provider.Lucene.LuceneIndexWithSpatial, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Spatial">
```

It seems that I have it all in place and working correctly, and there are no errors even when debugging through the code but still no results. Does anyone have a working solution for this in 8.1 that can guide me on 
where something might be misconfigured or not setup properly?

I have followed all the directions and steps below to get to this point. Any help is appreciated!

[Lucene spatial search with sitecore 8.2](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/494/lucene-spatial-search-with-sitecore-8-2)

http://www.sitecorecoding.com/2014/11/Sitecore-ContentSearch-With-Spatial-Search.html

Comment: Just to make sure, when you use the Content Search API without the SpacialSearchResult, it does yield results right?

Comment: Yes, all my other results for search are working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that by working with Ahmed Okour on this issue, I was missing this one line of code:

```
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/spatialLuceneIndexConfiguration">
```

to replace this line of code:

```
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration">
```

Basically, the wrong index configuration was being called upon. This is the correct index configuration:

```
<indexConfigurations>
        <spatialLuceneIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration"  type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <documentBuilderType>Sitecore.ContentSearch.Spatial.Indexing.LuceneSpatialDocumentBuilder, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Spatial</documentBuilderType>
        </spatialLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
```

Now, it's working and I am getting correct results back. Happy coding!